# Long tags cut off when creating filter

Tags: bug, tags, design, custom-filters

On Arqade, I was trying to create a filter that will catch 'em all, but I saw that long tags get cut off, making it impossible to remove the tag without resorting to [using the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JYRU.png) (which is a little unintuitive):

[image: Cursor at beginning of line]

(Some even wider tags have their last letters cut off.)

As you can see, there is plenty of grey space to the right of the box, so there's no reason why it couldn't be bigger.

Comment: How would this go on mobile? Do tags really have to be that long?

Comment: @Mast I have one of the smallest phones and even then there’s room to the right to make the box bigger, because of how things move around. I’m not sure what to say about tag length other than the max is now 35 and we’re not going back.